# C89 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c89

Is there a way to configure the default C compiler from Microsoft Visual Studio **2013** to compile in the **C89** standard?

I've tried /Za option, but doesn't switch back to C89 mode.

Comment: The C compiler in VS only supports C89, it can't compile any other dialect of C. There's no need to configure that.

Comment: MSVC doesn't support targeting specific standards versions like GCC does. If you need to restrict support to something closer to C89/C90, you'll need to use an older version of MSVC.

Comment: @user3477950: MS has started adding support for C99 features. For example VC++ 2013 supports designated initializers and mixing declarations with code (finally!). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx